# Oracle Apex 19.2 Session Sharing not working

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a bunch of apps e.g. App1, App2 ,App3 and so on. Each app is independent from others but all of them use the LDAPS authentication scheme so the "account" used to login is the same.

I set up a db table (tblUserApps) in which I match each app with the users that is allowed to use it and join with the apex view **apex_applications**. I modify the value of **home_link** field (*f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.*) replacing the *&APP_ID.* part with the appID in tblUserApps.

The link in apex page is like this:

```
User | AppID ---> home_link used in apex
------------
UsrA | 101   ---> f?p=101:1:&SESSION.
UsrA | 102   ---> f?p=102:1:&SESSION.
UsrB | 101   ---> f?p=101:1:&SESSION.
UsrB | 103   ---> f?p=103:1:&SESSION.
UsrC | 102   ---> f?p=102:1:&SESSION.
...  | ...
```

For each app in apex I set the auth scheme with the same cookie name for custom session sharing but every app I access requests the login.

I found a solution [here](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2019/01/oracle-apex-application-session-sharing.html) but after setting the same cookie name for each app the login page is shown every time I try to pass to a different app.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "lists all the applications enabled for a logged user"? You control which apps share sessions as the developer. Just show a list of apps, no? 2) What do you mean by "after setting the same name for each app"? Do you mean the Cookie Name?

Comment: @DanMcGhan : your questions are correct so I rewrite my post in a (I hope) clear way

Comment: How did you configure the link in the "app directory" app to the other apps? Are you passing the session id, that's necessary?

Comment: @DanMcGhan : I join the apex_applications view and "build" the URL passing the session

Comment: If you'd like to meet online so that I can see the app and offer suggestions, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/). If you do reach out, please include the URL to this Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @DanMcGhan : Thanks so much for your contact but it make me thinking that the "setup" I describe is expected to work correctly so debugging the app I found that was my mistake in building the URL. I report the solution in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the comments received I realized that I was missing something obvious, and it was just like that.

The configuration of auth scheme is correct as described in *grassroot-oracle post*. The error was in the way I build the applications home_link.

I build the URL not in Apex but in db (view) and I use the syntax *&SESSION.* that result in a ***string*** and the final URL was exactly `f?p=101:1:&SESSION.`
Using the syntax *V('SESSION')* the final url becomes `f?p=101:1:123456789` and all wark correctly as expected.

Useful links:

[Understanding URL Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03020)

[Referencing Session State](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_ses_val.htm#HTMDB03012)

Comment: While `SESSION` was once used, it has a different meaning in Oracle Database. APEX developers should use `APP_SESSION` instead. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/understanding-substitution-strings.html#GUID-34118202-1B85-4D38-8C27-F819679504DB